# puts objectname not working

Tags: ruby

In the following code, `puts ParentObjectC2` is not working. I was referring to an online tutorial.

```
class BaseParentClass
    def method
        100
    end
end

class Child1 < BaseParentClass
    puts "I am child class one , I inherit the properties of BaseParentClass"
    ParentObjectC1=BaseParentClass.new
    puts ParentObjectC1.method
end

class Child2 < BaseParentClass
    puts "I am child two, I also inherit the properties of BaseParentClass"
    ParentObjectC2=BaseParentClass.new
    puts ParentObjectC2
end
```

My output

```
ragesh@ragesh:~/Ruby/HelloWorld$ ruby classDemo.rb
I am child class one , I inherit the properties of BaseParentClass
100
I am child two, I also inherit the properties of BaseParentClass
#<BaseParentClass:0x00000001423bb8>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why is my question downvoted ??? Isn't it valid ? 
Mods kindly be sensible before downvoting a question. I did search for a solution and couldnt find one.

Comment: Your question was very likely not downvoted by moderators (moderators have other tools at their disposal, although they prefer to not use their powers and let the community do their thing) but by users, and the reason was probably because, well, your question doesn't actually contain any question.

Answer (score 0):

Add a to_s method to the base class if you want to print in sensibly. In the first subclass, you print the method function. In the second, you try to print the object itself.

And please, use lowercase object names. Uppercase just looks like a class

```
def to_s
 "base #{method}"
end
```

One more thing. You can call the method directly. Do not create a base object and call it on the base. This does not illustrate inheritance at all!

Instead just call:

`puts method`